# Unexpected valid syntax in annotated assignment expression

Tags: python, syntax, type-annotation

Apparently (and surprisingly, to me at least), this is a perfectly valid expression in Python 3.6+:

```
x: 10
```

What is up with this? I checked it out using the `ast` module and got the following:

```py
[ins] In [1]: ast.parse('x: 10').body
Out[1]: [<_ast.AnnAssign at 0x110ff5be0>]
```

Okay so it's an annotated assignment. I looked up the [grammar reference](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/grammar.html) and saw that it corresponds to this rule:

```
annassign: ':' test ['=' test]
```

This doesn't make a lot of sense to me. If it's an annotated *assignment*, then why is the assignment portion of the expression optional? What could it possibly mean if the assignment portion of the expression isn't present? Isn't that really strange?

The `annasign` node is only referenced in one rule:

```
expr_stmt: testlist_star_expr (annassign | augassign (yield_expr|testlist) |
                     ('=' (yield_expr|testlist_star_expr))*)
```

In each of the other possible projections at that level, some kind of assignment expression is required (`augassign` is a token like `+=`). So why is it optional for `annassign`?

I guess it's plausible that this is intended to be the annotated version of a bare name expression (i.e. just `x`), but it's really quite confusing. I'm not too familiar with the static type checkers out there but can they make use of an annotation like this?

More than likely this is intentional, but it kind of seems like a bug. It's a little bit problematic, because it's possible to write syntactically valid but utterly nonsensical code like this:

```
a = 1
b = 2
c: 3 # see what I did there? oops!
d = 4
```

I recently made a similar mistake in my own code when I converted a `dict` representation into separate variables, and only got caught out when my test pipeline ran in a Python 3.5 environment and produced a `SyntaxError`.

Anyway, I'm mostly just curious about the intent, but would also be really excited to find out that I discovered an actual grammar bug.

Comment: the intended use-case would be something like (forgive the lack of indentation): `x: int; if blah: x = 3 else: x = 2` *or* as annotations for a class, which just go in the class body like that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's classified as an annotated assignment for parser reasons. If there were separate `annotation` and `annassign` rules, Python's LL(1) parser wouldn't be able to tell which one it's supposed to be parsing when it sees the colon.

Comment: That makes sense. Implicit in your answer is the fact that this is valid syntax. Unfortunately i haven't been able to explore these kinds of type annotations very much since my projects have had to be compatible with older Python versions.